# R: Convert Matrix to YES, NO dataframe

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, apply

I have a matrix like this

```
df <- matrix(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3)),nrow=3,ncol=2)

df: 
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    2
```

I want to convert every cell value to `YES`, if greater than 0, else `NO`

I understand that I can do this using

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 0, "Yes","No"))
```

However my matrix is very huge (million * 5000), and hence using apply takes insanely large time

I have also tried

```
df <- ifelse(df > 0, "Yes","No")
```

However even this takes a lot of time

Can I achieve better performance with this?

Comment: Why do you need `"Yes"/"No"`. Just do `df > 0` and get `TRUE/FALSE` instead

Comment: Have you tried using `replace`?

Comment: @Bati: replace can be used for each column (vector), I need to do this for all columns, will it help?

Comment: thanks David: that worked, can you please add that to the answer , that was really helpful

Comment: `df > 0` or if negative values are not possible `df[] <- as.logical(df)`. Creating character values is not necessary and less efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to create the matrix:

```
df[] <- c("No", "Yes")[(df > 0) + 1]
```

The result:

```
     [,1]  [,2] 
[1,] "Yes" "Yes"
[2,] "Yes" "Yes"
[3,] "Yes" "Yes"
```

Comment: why have you added +1 here?

Comment: @Username The command `df > 0` returns a logical vector with `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s. In mathematical operations, `TRUE` represents 1 and `FALSE` represents 0. Since I add 1, the resulting vectors contains 1s and 2s. These values are used for indexing the  vector `c("No", "Yes")` of length 2.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to visually examine the matrix, and not use the contents, theThe `symnum` function is designed for this use in particular. The Description section of `?symnum` says

> Symbolically encode a given numeric or logical vector or array. Particularly useful for visualization of structured matrices, e.g., correlation, sparse, or logical ones.

```
symnum(df, cutpoints=c(-Inf, 0, Inf), symbols=c("no", "yes"))

[1,] yes yes
[2,] yes yes
[3,] yes yes
```